# Rails 3 - Update multiple records with one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a simple inventory app, and I was wanting to have a page with a list of items, with only a name label and an editable box to update the instock amount and a single update button to update them all.

My model is named item and with two fields, name and instock

I'm not sure if you need more info, thanks.

***** After playing around with it, I'm able to build the form, but when I click on update, it gives the error:
Couldn't find Item with ID=edit_multiple

Here is part of my controller:

```
   def edit_multiple
 @items = Item.find(params[:id])
```

And here is my routes.rb

```
resources :items do
collection do
  get :search
  post :edit_multiple
  put :update_multiple
end
```

if anyone has any pointers or help, I'd appreciate it.

thanks,

Comment: and where/what is the problem?

Comment: Basically, I can follow along those screencasts up until the submit section, then I'm not getting the edit / update_multiple peiece

Answer (score 6):

Check out these screencasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to follow along with those, but I get stuck at the submit action. I'm not following how to edit my routes.rb file to follow along I believe. Here is mine route.rb: '  resources :items do
    collection do
      get :search
    end'

Comment: what is the difference between 198 and 165?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by manually describing the path to the controller action in the edit_multiple form, like this:

```
= semantic_form_for :isbn, :url => {:controller => 'isbns', :action => 'update_multiple'}, :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f|
```