# Updating multiple records in a single submit? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm

I'm a newbie to rails and am having some difficulty...

I have a page displaying a list of records in a table and would like for the user to be able to make changes, submit the form, to run validation and persist the data.

This is what I have so far:

View:

```
- @people.each do |p|
  %tr
    %td
      %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "person_id[]", :value => p.id}
      %input{:name => "firstname[]", :value => p.firstname}
    %td
      %input{:name => "lastname[]", :value => p.lastname}
```

Example parameters being posted to the controller:

```
"person_id"=>["12", "13", "14"], 
"firstname"=>["john", "joe", "mary"], 
"lastname"=>["smith", "bloggs", "jane"],
```

At this point I am scared, because I am no longer bound to an active record. Instead I feel myself wanting to write some messy code to loop over the person_id array to see what has changed and write any changes back.

This feels bad because I have to explicitly compare each field, also if something fails due to a validation error half way through how should I rollback any changes and display the messages to the user?

I'm hoping that due to my rails ignorance this whole approach is wrong and I am missing a trick. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to approach this problem?

Comment: Have a look at the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/q/5583568/800526 - more specifically http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have an **association** setup between `people model` and `person model`, by looking at the hidden `person_id` field in your view code.
If your associations are rightly setup, use

> **accepts_nested_attributes_for**

and follow the [Rails guides for association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).
At this point of time, I can only help you this much, as not much information is provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks, been trying this approach, but according to the docs update is only for 1:1 relationships. "Allows you to specify that an existing record may only be updated. A new record may only be created when there is no existing record. This option only works for one-to-one associations and is ignored for collection associations. This option is off by default." : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for